# Eclipse XML editor: refresh content assist

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I'm using eclipse WTP plugin to create an XML grammar. I wrote a set of XML Schema and I'm using an XML file to test if the grammar works correctly. The Eclipse content assist works like a charm but every time that I change something in the grammar, the autocomplete feature of the xml editor is not refreshed with the new changes. If I close and re-open the project, content assist is updated with the new definitions.

Is there a way to force the refresh of the content assist for the XML editor without closing and re-opening the project every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find that when the **XML Editor** is active, there's a **Reload Dependencies** button on the toolbar to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I normally just close and open the file i'm working on and it refreshes.

IE, if I add a new line in the documentation element in my schema, when I close and open the file, mousing over the element will now show the new documentation.

I'm not sure if this is what you want.